# $http content-type: application/json throws 500 internal server error

Tags: angularjs, content-type

I am making a post call like below with default content-type: application/json
But it throws

> 500 internal server error.

Should I change the content-type or encode the request data I send.

I tried using Content-Type:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.
```

which didn't turn out well

```
   $http(
            {
                url: '/api/sitecore/Appointment/AppointmentConfirmation',
                method: 'POST',
                data: "__RequestVerificationToken":"7zK0TTYLMpMtsKl11vVKI-vTK5-Mz-ViAqNKqL-aSLv3SKLCu807C10e9z8FkSFF0Av2NWeaI8R47CuBtNND6cA1"

            }
        )
```

Comment: "500 Internal Error" just means "Something went wrong. If you are the developer: read the server logs to find out what". It doesn't tell us anything about how to fix the problem. Maybe sending a different content-type will solve it. Maybe it won't. That's just pure speculation. (Changing the content-type header without changing the type of content you are sending is probably doomed to failure though).

Comment: the same call when entered in console is working fine and returns status 200.(with content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.). so there is something am missing out from client side

Comment: Can you add the curl of the request with valid auth tokens, so that I could replicate it?